# Storyboard animations and attached properties in Metro app

Tags: .net, windows, animation, microsoft-metro

I have a very specific use case, and a pretty weird issue in implementing it. In my Metro app, I have a few images that I want to move on user interaction. Let's say, an image of a chess piece, for example. Since, I can't follow pointer movement here to animate, I am using a storyboard animation to get things done.

So, what I essentially have is a Canvas for the whole game board, and a small chess piece image at the bottom corner. Initial setup is simple as I can set the Top and Left property of the chess piece manually. To move the chess piece, I am just calculating the new Top and Left property depending on the move. For example, if player moves pawn upwards, value of Top changes by (Canvas.Height / 8) but Left property stays same. Now, till here, everything is fine. Only problem is, this causes image to jump from initial to final location, instead of an smooth movement.

So, I have created storyboard for animating the top and left position as below.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="storyboard">
    <DoubleAnimation x:Name="playerLeftAnimation" Storyboard.TargetName="playerPiece"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Canvas.Left" 
                     EnableDependentAnimation="True"    
                     Duration="0:0:2" />
    <DoubleAnimation x:Name="playerTopAnimation" Storyboard.TargetName="playerPiece"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Canvas.Top" 
                     EnableDependentAnimation="True"    
                     Duration="0:0:2" />
</Storyboard>
```

This works well, if I use this method for normal dependency properties like Fontsize. Here playerPiece is the image name. Canvas is unnamed. But, here it gives me exception saying "Unable to resolve the target property of story board". Am I missing something to be set? Or should I try other way to animate the position of an image? If yes, any idea, which is the best way?

Answer (score 2):

Solved, thanks to MSDN. Just needed to mention targetproperty as "(Canvas.Left)" instead of "Canvas.Left".